# Custom Fivestar widget does not appear on display settings

Tags: hooks

I need to create a custom wiget for Fivestars. I create module, and implement `hook_fivestar_widgets()`. I create css file, images. And it works on Open Server on my PC. When I upload this module on hosting and turn it on I see my widget in admin menu but it does not appear on node display settings.
[image]

```
/**
 * @return array with pair - widget css path, widget name
 * implements hook_fivestar_widgets()
 */
function fivestar_widget_fivestar_widgets() {

  $widgets = [
    'sites/all/modules/fivestar_widget/style.css' => 'squares',
  ];

  return $widgets;
}
```

Comment: You sure flushed the cache already and reloaded the page?

Comment: Yes, i reload page, clear all caches, but system render default widget

Comment: I find the same problem here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/168249/custom-fivestar-widget-does-not-display-custom-icons But i cant understand how i can use it. Can anyone help with it?